# Degrees of comparison

Tags: superlatives, comparative-degree

> 1. This girl **is more** intelligent than the rest of the class.
> 2. This girl **is the most** intelligent than the rest of the class.

Which one is the right one? As far as I know, we use "than + comparative adjective" for comparison, but "the rest of the class" makes me confused.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is grammatically correct!

'Most' means the best out of a group, so you could say "This girl is the most intelligent girl in the class." if you wanted.